# Поочередный вывод данных из двух массивов(php+mysql)

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. Никак не придумывается алгоритм вывода данных из двух массивов полученных из двух таблиц базы.
начальный код таков :

```
$qM = "SELECT * FROM `male` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT ".$cnt." , 10";
$qF = "SELECT * FROM `female` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT ".$cnt." , 10";
$Male = $Db->query($qL);
$Female = $Db->query($qF);
```

Необходимо вывести данные поочередно:

```
мальчик возраст имя рост вес
девочка возраст имя рост вес
мальчик...
девочка...
```

Comment: Может быть, я чего-то не понимаю, но как насчет выводить их поочередно?
while(...){  echo $m[...],$m[...],...;  echo $f[...],$f[...],...;}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$male = $db->query($qM); //Обращение к базе[0];
$female = $db->query($qF); //Обращение к базе[1];
while($row = $male -> fetch_assoc()) //Перебор полученных строк;
{
$row = $female -> fetch_assoc();
echo("Мальчик: ".$row['возраст']." ".$row['имя']." ".$row['рост']." ".$row['вес']);
echo("<br>Девочка: ".$row['возраст']." ".$row['имя']." ".$row['рост']." ".$row['вес']);
}
```

---

В скрипте 'возраст', 'имя', 'рост', 'вес' - это названия соответствующих им полей таблиц, их нужно заменить.

---

Совет: никогда не используйте "SELECT *", не поленитесь перечислить поля, потому что таблица часто расширяется, а код не переписывается, в итоге мы получаем лишние запросы.

Comment: Честно говоря я не понял момент с fetch_assoc(). Каким образом оно работает?

Comment: Обрабатывает полученные данные, занося их в ассоциативный массив. Аналогичная функция fetch_row() занесет полученные данные в обычный массив.